# Draggable element in sortable goes out of scrollbar

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I Have a long nested list to which i apply overflow-y:Auto, each of the element has sortable widget attached to it.

Now the issue which we are facing is that the drag-gable element goes out of scroll-bar container which is not desirable, i do understand that the position is set to absolute and z-Index to 1000 and i also understand while dragging the element it takes into consideration the height of the parent element and it let me drag up-to that calculated height only.

Changing the position to relative makes me drag the element only inside the scrollbar but then also the hieght it lets me drag upto is too much.

Desired Behavior:We should be able to drag the element only inside the scrollbar and that too not beyond the last element bottom offset position.

The piece of code is as follows:

```
$(".sortableList").sortable({
axis: 'y',
containment: 'parent',
tolerance: 'pointer',
distance: 5,
start: function (event, ui) {
    $(ui.item).find('#contain').hide(10, 'swing');
    $(ui.item).addClass('setHeight');
    ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
    $(".sortableList").sortable('refresh');
},
stop: function (event, ui) {
    $('#contain').show(10, 'swing');
    $(ui.item).removeClass('setHeight');
}
```

});

Js fiddle link for the issue is :  http://jsfiddle.net/hK7YT/2/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to mostly work by playing with the `containment` option: http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/hK7YT/3/. The containment works unless you scroll the lists to sort—and that is documented issue with jQuery UI itself (http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9460). I would advise giving the lists as much height as you can in your UI to avoid the need to scroll.

Comment: The given solution is not working for us; if we do so the selected item jump off from its actual position which is happening in shared fiddle demo. Also, the suggestion of giving height won't be possible for me as I have 'N' numbers of node; which is dynamic.